# Error : unknown type name 'FeatureTracks'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, android-ndk

I had made an structure for feature tracks:

```
struct FeatureTracks{
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f> > tracks;
    std::vector<size_t> offset;
};
```

Then making a function to call it:

```
void genTrackMatrix(const std::vector<cv::Mat>& images, FeatureTracks& trackMatrix, int tWindow,  int stride);
```

But the function calling is giving an error:unknown type name 'FeatureTracks'

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not give enough informations. Detail how you organized the concerned files, have you put the right includes, are you sure about your build process ?

Comment: Yes I am sure about the build process. My include files are:#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <Eigen>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <opencv2/core/types.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include <fstream>

Comment: Please detail how and where you have declared and defined `FeatureTracks` and `genTrackMatrix`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I assume, that it is simply not defined. The struct definition must be done before the function prototype declaration. Is the struct defined within another c file? Then move it to a header file and include the Header. Is the struct definition later in the c file? Then move it to the beginning.

The C-Compiler has no global scope, it only sees the current file and processes it top-down. Just "play" being a compiler and step through the C-file. Have you seen every type definition before it is used?

Comment: Thank you @Thomas I had defined the structure after the defination of function. Thank you that solved my problem.